# Is there a way to reset password with Firebase Auth inside a ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web app, I have a forgot password functionality and I ma using firebase.

My question: is there a way to reset password with Firebase Auth inside an ASP.NET MVC web app?

I don't want to use their UI page and they also don't have confirm new password.
I only use Firebase for log in(basically to handle registration and login's). I do not use Firebase as my database it only for login's and register the users only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of the following documentation from the firebase website - this should be able to help.

```
async Task< string > GeneratePasswordResetLinkAsync(string email, ActionCodeSettings settings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

[Firebase authentication docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/auth/abstract-firebase-auth#class_firebase_admin_1_1_auth_1_1_abstract_firebase_auth_1a64c59fa408389e06bc026e5e0bf4e7d9)

Kia Kaha Mike Smith